# UIMA Ruta how to annotate a part of input string

Tags: string, uima, ruta

I have an input string (ex. 'abcdefgh'), all i need is to make an annotation with a part of this string (ex. 'cd'), in other words i need to substring an input string and mark an annotation with it. How can i do this?

Comment: You may try a `(?<=^.{2}).{2}` regex

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried ANY{REGEXP("(?<=^.{2}).{2}") -> MARK(MyAnnotation)}, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It is strange, documentation says the regex flavor is Java.

Comment: The regex is appllied with the matches method on the matched text of the rule element, thus the regex will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

New annotations are always only created using the offsets of existing annotations with normal rules. In you case, you match on annotation pf the type `ANY` and apply a condition on the text covered by each annotation. The condition matches the regex on the complete text, therefore the condition fails.

In order to create annotations that are smaller than the smallest annotations available, e.g., within tokens, you cannot use the normal UIMA Ruta rules. You need to apply simple regex rules that do not rely on annotations for the matching process. Here's an example:

```
ANY->{"cd" -> MyType};
```

This rule matches on each `ANY` annotation and applies an inlined rule on each covered text. The inlined rule is a simple regex rule with the regex `cd`. If the pattern is found, a new annotation of the type `MyType` is created there.

If you do something like this, you should select the matching type carefully, e.g., use something else but `ANY`.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*